# Proof of $rms(x)^2=avg(x)^2+std(x)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am trying to derive the proof of $rms(x)^2=avg(x)^2+std(x)^2$ but I am stuck at one line.

$std(x)^2= (1/n)||x-(1^Tx/n)1||^2=(1/n)[x^Tx-2x^T(1^Tx/n)1+n(1^Tx/n)^2]$

So from this, how can I proceed? I know that:

$std(x)^2=rms(x)^2+(1/n)[-2x^T(1^Tx/n)1+n(1^Tx/n)^2]$ is left for me. The book that I use used some sort of property I guess to get the equality:

$-2x^T(1^Tx/n)1=(2/n)(1^Tx)^2$

I know that we can move around $n$ because it's a constant, but I don't understand how $x^T1^Tx1=(1^Tx)^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved it. We want to prove that $x^T1^Tx1=(1^Tx)^2$

1:

Let $x=\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           x_{n}
         \end{bmatrix}
 $  and we know that $1^Tx= \sum x_i$.

Then $1^Tx1=\begin{bmatrix}
           \sum x_i \\
           \sum x_i \\
           \vdots \\
           \sum x_i
         \end{bmatrix}$.

Then $x^T1^Tx1= \begin{bmatrix}
           x_1, x_2
           \dots 
           x_n
         \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
           \sum x_i \\
           \sum x_i \\
           \vdots \\
           \sum x_i
         \end{bmatrix}=$

$x_1\sum x_i+x_2\sum x_i\dots+x_n\sum x_i=\sum x_i\sum x_i=(\sum x_i)^2=(1^Tx)^2$

If there's a more cleaner and more intuitive method I'd glad to hear it!